# Why is 3<<1 == 6 in python?

Tags: python, operators, bit-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Absolute Beginner's Guide to Bit Shifting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting)

anyone can explain me that operator << or >>

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `<<` and `>>` operators are [bitshift operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts). `x << 1` shifts all the bits in `x` up to the next most significant bit, effectively multiplying by 2. More generally, `x << n` shifts the bits up n positions. To understand how this operation works it is easiest to look at the [binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system) representation:

```
3         0000011 =  3
3 << 1    0000110 =  6
3 << 2    0001100 = 12
3 << 3    0011000 = 24
```

Similarly the `>>` operator shifts the bits down:

```
58        0111010 = 58
58 >> 1   0011101 = 29
58 >> 2   0001110 = 14
58 >> 3   0000111 = 7
58 >> 4   0000011 = 3
58 >> 5   0000001 = 1
58 >> 6   0000000 = 0
```

Answer (score 15):

3, in binary, is `11` and shifted to left one bit is `110`, or 6 in decimal.

Think of `a << b` as `a * (2 ** b)`

`>>` is for right-shifting. Think of `a >> b` as `a // (2 ** b)`

Comment: Python isn't BASIC, so `a<<b` would be equivalent to `a*2**b` or `a*(2**b)` (and likewise for `>>`.

Comment: -1 Think of `a << b` as `a * 2 ** b`

Comment: @martineau of course, I was trying to write it in a more readable format. But you are right. Modified.

Comment: Might be better expressed as `a*pow(2,b)`.

Comment: @John Machin - Thanks for including the use of `//`.  I think a lot of people are going to be surprised that `/` always means floating point division in Python3.

Answer (score 4):

It's a shift operator.

http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit shift, using a [shifting operation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations).

Say you have a number, and looking at the lowest bits, you have 3:

0 0 1 1

If you shift it, you'll get 6, or:

0 1 1 0