# Python 3 - What is ">>"

Tags: python-3.x, bit-shift

This is the confusing line: `x_next = (x_next + (a // x_prev)) >> 1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is 3<<1 == 6 in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917948/why-is-31-6-in-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is bit-wise shift. The next will give you some intuitions:

```
>>> 16 >> 1
8
>>> 16 >> 2
4
>>> 16 >> 3
2
>>> bin(16)
'0b10000'
>>> bin(16 >> 1)
'0b1000'
>>> bin(16 >> 2)
'0b100'
```

Answer (score 3):

The `>>` operator is the same operator as it is in C and many other languages.

A bitshift to the right. If your number is like this in binary: `0100` than it will be `0010` after `>> 1`. With `>> 2` it will be `0001`.

So basically it's a nice way to divide your number by 2 (while flooring the remainder) ;)

Comment: In what sense is this a nice way to divide by 2? A nice way to divide by 2 would be to write `x // 2`.

Comment: Yes, but I doubt in Python this is a "nice" way to divide number by `2` :) There is `//` operator for that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I totally agree this is **not** a nice way to floor divide number by 2.

Comment: In my implementation of Python 2, shifting is about 15% faster than dividing by 2. That's about all that the shift operator has in its favour here. Given all the other operations it seems rather pointless optimisation. Especially as you could do it with the sqrt function even faster one would imagine!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, @Tadeck: it was a joke, hence the `;)`. On a more serious note, the bitshift is usually faster and takes only a fraction of the instructions compared to a `sqrt` or `div` operation. Just look up the instructions for your basic `x86` cpu :)

Answer (score 1):

It is the [right shift operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations).

Here it is being used to divide by 2. It would be far more clear to write this as

```
x_next = (x_next + (a // x_prev)) // 2
```

Sadly a lot of people try to be clever and use shift operators in place of multiplication and division. Typically this just leads to lots of confusion for the poor individuals who have to read the code at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

Most newer/younger programmers do not worry about efficiency because the computers are so fast.

But if you are working on a 8-bit or 16-bit processor that may or may not have a hardware multiply and rarely has a hardware divide, then shifting integers takes one machine cycle while a multiply may take 16 or more and a divide may take 50-200 machine cycles. When your processor clock is in the GHz range you do not notice the difference, but if your instruction rate is 8 MHz or less it adds up very quickly.

So for efficiency people shift to multiply or divide for powers of two, especially in C which is the most common language for small processors and controllers.

I see it so often that I do not even think about it anymore.

Some of the things I do in C:

x = y >> 3; // is the same ad the floor of a divide by 8

if (y & 0x04) x++; // adds the rounding so the answer is rounded

For most microcontrollers, the compiler lets you see the resulting machine code generated and you can see what different statements generate. With that type of feedback, after awhile you just start writing more efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

It means "right shift". It works the same as floor division by `2`:

```
>>> a = 7
>>> a >> 1
3
>>> a // 2
3
```